# CSS/HTML Centre Box

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im looking at this beautiful piece of webdesign, notice how the box is perfectly centered in the middle of the screen, I have looked through the source code of the page but it does not make much sense to me.

([Web site Link to view full example, click here](http://gzscripts.com/CarRentalScript/index.php?controller=GzPreview&action=index))

All I can really make out is that they are using, the below code at the top of their stylesheet.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In short I would like to know what would be the easiest and most efficient way to center a box like on the image on the center of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `#preview-container-id` style. That's what makes it in the center. And they're using the same style or maybe even bootstrapped the bootstrap library. Have a look at it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the box you want to center a `margin: 0 auto;`.

Though you will also need to make sure the item can be centered. For this, correct its width to be less than the full width of the HTML `<body>`.

[image]

As you can see in this image, the real magic is being done by the following code:

```
#preview-container-id {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

With this, they executed the two steps mentioned in my answer.

If you de-activate those two properties you'll notice that the box goes all the way to the left.

And just as **Luke Robertson** mentioned, there are different ways to approach this. My solution is for a block-level item, but if you had an inline-level item this solution would not work at all.

**Answer for comment Q's:**

The `box-sizing: border-box` sums up all the cumulative width and height set by margins and padding with the size defined for the elements.

Notice the size of the highlighted element without left padding and with border-box active:
[image: Item with left padding de-activated and border-box active]

Now, check the width with the left padding active:

[image: Item with left padding and border-box active]

Do you see any change?

Now, lets de-activate border-box and leave the padding on:

[image: Item with left padding de-activated and border-box de-activated]

Now this looks ugly, and it's exactly what `border-box` prevents

As you can see on a quote from [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/) CSS-Tricks post:

> This is often called "universal box-sizing", and it's a good way to work! The (literal) width you set is the width you get, without having to perform mental math and manage the complexity that comes from widths that come from multiple properties.

And no, you don't need to set any extra CSS on the `<body>` or `<html>` tags, as they already come with the required properties to allow you center block-level items :)

Comment: Thank you antonio, what exactly does the `*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}` do? I searched for `box-sizing` at W3Schools but their example wasnt very good

Comment: Also would I have to apply any CSS to the `body,html` to keep it centered?

Comment: Box model is how the browser positions margins, paddings and widths, explained here : http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2013-11-17-box-model-behaviour/

Comment: Yeah, and the documentation even explains the point that you need to sum up all four boxes sizes to get your element true size (w/o using `border-box`).

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="center-me">
 //div content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center-me {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 80%;
}
```

There are different way to do this, it depends if your parent element is a block or not

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Flexbox to center both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

```js
window.onload = (function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
  container.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}); // end window.onload
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: skyblue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <span id='box'>Box centered horizontally and vertically.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They have taken a div after the starting of body

```
        <div id="preview-container-id">
```

And then they apply css to them

View these you will understand what is going on that link which you have provided

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GISbz.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wy4v.png)

Answer (score -1):

HTML :

```
<div class='parent_element'>
   <div class='child_element'>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.parent_element{
    float:left;width:100%;text-align:center;
}
.child_element{
    float:none;display:block;margin:0 auto;width:80%;
}
```

Comment: Why float the parent left, set a 100% width on a div, text align center it ?

Then set float none on the child (divs are not floated naturally) and they are all ready block elements ...

the only 2 peice of css you need are the last 2 rules

Comment: Only margin:0 auto; will not work if you don't give 100% width and float:left or display:block to it's parent div. and if child element is only display blocke than it works but if not than you should give float:none to works with margin:0 auto; and parent element give text align center because if not given centered align than child element can be floated left or follow inherited style

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRZgmQ

divs are 100% by default and you dont need to float anything ...

Comment: @Luke You are right and I apologize for my statement but if "parent div has some different styles" than It will affect to child div.